# How to place a running header and a footer to the page with chapter/section heading?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

Some people wants to remove running headers and footers from the pages, where a chapter or a section is begining. But I'd like to *stay* it in place. How can I make it? (I use KOMA-Script (scrbook) and scrpage2.)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `scrpage2` and its `scrheadings` pagestyle, pages that were formerly assigned the `plain` style (e.g. chapter starting pages) will now be assigned `scrplain`. The header/footer commands of `scrpage2` feature an optional argument that controls the `scrplain` style.

A possible source of confusion is that commands like `\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}` may still produce an empty heading on chapter starting pages because `\headmark` itself may be empty (e.g. because it refers to `\rightmark` in twoside documents). Using e.g. `\leftmark` should produce non-empty "starting" headings.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot% Dump header/footer content
% \ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}% Will produce empty "starting" heading
\ohead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{whatever}`, see the documentation scrguien, section 3.2.2. Page Style.