# Header and footer missing on sites with chapter

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, footer

I'm using facyhdr and everytime I make a new chapter, the site has no more header or footer. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,abstracton,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-0.3cm}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%titelpage

\newpage\thispagestyle{fancy}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: are you sure you want `\let\clearpage\relax `  (it is likely to break things:-) `\chapter` issues `\thspagestyle{plain}` so by default you get no header, fancyhdr has a fancyplain declaration for changing that style

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18355/579 , https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8690/579

Comment: Using `fancyhdr` in combination with a KOMA script class like `scrreprt` should be avoided (you should also obtain a warning about it). Instead migrating to `scrlayer-scrpage` is recommended in the documentation.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}`

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage